# Take a sample of an array without numpy or pandas in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to create a "pythonic" way of taking a small subset of a very large array in python.

I am currently taking in a csv with 58 columns and 4960 rows with the following codes:

```
def import_normal_csv(file):
    # Create blank array
    results = []
    # Open file
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        # read in file changing values to floats
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        for row in reader:
            results.append(row)
    return results

def main():
    print(" Working SPAM Dataset... ")
    # Create a raw data array without numpy
    spam_raw_data = import_normal_csv('spam.csv')

    # CREATE SUBSET OF SPAM_RAW_DATA HERE

    random.shuffle(spam_raw_data)
```

I have seen various ways to do this using `numpy` or `pandas`, but I would like to do this naturally without those libraries. Instead of my massive array, how could I instead take in only...500 rows (or some arbitrary number significantly less than nearly 5000)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
subset_size = 500
random.sample(spam_raw_data, subset_size)
```

Also note your `import_normal_csv` function can be simplified:

```
def import_normal_csv(file):
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        return list(reader)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the builtin `random` library, for example:

```
import random

random.sample(data, 500)
```

This will give you a `list` of 500 `list`s, each representing one row.